# Vsftpd - different r/w permissions to one folder for different group of virtual users

Tags: permissions, vsftpd

I have configured Vsftpd on Ubuntu 16.04. Everything works fine, but I need one more thing.

Let's say I have:

- folder /var/www/folder1/uploads
- Virtual users: admin1, admin2, admin3, customer
- I use vsftpd_user_conf folder to store users local_root

I want adminX users to have permissions to r/w in 'folder1' and 'uploads', but I want user 'customer' to have only read permission to 'folder1' and read/write permission to 'uploads'.
Now I have situation that 'folder1' is read only and every user with access to /var/www/folder1 can write in 'uploads'.
Is it possible?

```
$ ls -la /var/www/folder1
drwxrwxr-x 3 root   root    4096 May  9 17:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root    4096 May  9 17:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 vsftpd nogroup 4096 May  9 17:15 upload


$ vsftpd.conf:
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
local_root=/var/www
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
hide_ids=YES
#virtual user settings
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
guest_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
nopriv_user=vsftpd
guest_username=vsftpd
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide `ls -la /var/www/folder1` and your `cat vsftpd.conf`?

And, may be, you can use this:

```
user_config_dir
```

This powerful option allows the override of any config option specified in the manual page, on a per-user basis. Usage is simple, and is best illustrated with an example:

If you set user_config_dir to be `/etc/vsftpd_user_conf` and then log on as the user `chris`, then `vsftpd` will apply the settings in the file `/etc/vsftpd_user_conf/chris` for the duration of the session.  The format of this file is as detailed in this manual page (see below link).

---

**PLEASE NOTE** that not all settings are effective on a per-user basis. For example, many settings only prior to the user's session being started. Examples of settings which will not affect any behaviour on a per-user basis include:

- listen_address
- banner_file
- max_per_ip
- max_clients
- xferlog_file
- etc...

By default no one of these are set.

---

from [Manpage VSFTPD.CONF](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html)